# Capture Value From Hidden ItemTemplate Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and I need to capture the value of my label, but have it not be displayed.  ANytime I set it to `hidden` I am no longer able to capture the value.  What should I alter so the label is hidden, but I still am able to capture the value?  `eghead` is what I am wanting to hide but still capture the value of

```
<td valign="top" style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridview1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="Both" ShowFooter="true" >
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="rdf" HeaderText="redfern" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("egh") %>' ID="eghead" ></asp:Label>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Sans" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Remember")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to get the value? Server or client code?

Comment: @DanielS - client code, I need to takea that value and use it as a parameter for an update statement.

Comment: Can u show me the client code which u are using to get value of that label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the

```
 style="display:none"
```

in the control. This way it will not be displayed in the UI but it will be available in the client side for manipulation.

Another alternative is to set a property of your checkbox and then use it using jquery or using javascript method. The asp.net renders the custom property as it is on client side.